# How to *properly* use interface types with WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf, interface

More specifically, the question is:
How to serialize a class with WCF that has (must have) interface types in property signatures because it implements an interface?

This is a design question. I'm not looking for a hack.
The purpose is to keep the interface definitions separate from implementing classes and hence not let interfaces refer to implementing classes.

I know that we're not supposed to pass around interfaces with WCF and 
also that there are still (non-interoperable) ways to do it (like using NetDataContractSerializer or the ServiceKnownType attribute), but that leaves me with the question: is there a proper way to use classes based on interfaces with WCF or should this not be attempted at all?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You can put DataContract and DataMember attributes on classes that inherit from interfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to my own specific problem.

The problem was that I was marking the properties (of an interface type) as DataMember. By instead marking corresponding private members as DataMember (and make sure that their types are concrete classes) the problem is solved.

Example:

```
[DataContract()]
public class Company : ICompany
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Employees")]
    private EmployeeList _employees;

    public IEmployeeList Employees { get { return _employees; }}
}
```

Comment: In that example, I fail to see what purpose having the interface fulfils... but presumably it makes sense in the wider context of the app

Comment: @Marc You're absolutely right. The necessity of the interface is part of the wider scheme and not explained here specifically but is considered a conditio sine qua non. (I suppose it often is).

Comment: Setting the private field as DataMember will throw a SecurityException if the application is run in a partially trusted domain.

Comment: @JDStuart Yes I know. This can be overcome by using an internal field instead of a private field and marking the assembly defining the data contracts with [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("System.Runtime.Serialization")] in assemblyinfo.cs.  See this link: http://blog.walteralmeida.com/2010/05/wcf-and-datacontract-serialization-internals-and-tips-.html

Answer (score 4):

Serialization is fundamentally about transporting *data*. Interfaces are about describing *behaviour*. Fundamentally these two things are completely orthogonal, IMO.

You can *possibly* make it work with `[KnownType(...)]` - and it would certainly help if you were using the same exact types at each end (assembly sharing), but this is very non-portable.

If you are after the idiomatic WCF usage for *portability*, you should probably restrict yourself to simple data contracts, which stand a chance of being useful to clients who know only the WSDL.

That said, I have no qualms torturing and abusing WCF to my own ends when it suits me ;p

Comment: Marc, I was aware of those things you mention. But my question remains: how do I solve this *design* problem? just not using interfaces anymore would be a very big sacrifice.

Comment: @Peladao use interfaces in your app: fine. But over the wire they have no meaning. If you want to **design** for that, then have a separate DTO layer with *no functionality* (except maybe auto-props) - just data. That is, ultimately, what you get on the wire.

Comment: Right, I was just starting to fear that I had to create a whole extra layer. However, I found an easier solution for the specific problem I had with some classes. See my own answer.